# How to use JDBC based database extension of GeoServer for other JDBC based database?

Tags: geoserver, geotools, mapd

I'm doing R&D on GeoServer for my project requirement to access JDBC based Database(MapD).

So to do that GeoServer provided some extension for particular database access extension like JDBC based extension sql server,but in my scenario database is another that also have JDBC based driver.

I got github geotools link but didn't get which classes and method used for make extension and  how going on process.

So To make GeoServer extension for JDBC based database, which java classes and method need to change and make jar file to put into lib folder to access database on GeoServer.

So any help me how to do in steps.

Comment: but i want which are mainly classes and method used for jdbc based extension?

Comment: could you tell me flow steps wise with a example